# Problem connecting tables in Sequelize-Typescript NestJS

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, nestjs, backend

There are 3 tables: users, posts, likes, (roles - but it works fine). One user has multiple posts and multiples likes. One post has multiple likes. As I understand, connections are

```
User @HasMany(() => Post) and @HasMany(() => Like)
Post @HasMany(() => Like)
```

**Problem**: In my `user.service.ts` when I run this function

```
        const user = await this.userRepository.findOne({ where: { email }, include: { all: true } })
        return user
```

it gets **Error**:
`likes.userId column does not exist`

**Code**:
Users ->

```
@Table({ tableName: 'users' })
export class User extends Model<User> {
    @Column({ type: DataType.INTEGER, unique: true, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true })
    id: number;
    
    @Column({ type: DataType.STRING, unique: true, allowNull: false })
    email: string;
    
    @Column({ type: DataType.STRING, allowNull: false })
    password: string;
    
    @BelongsToMany(() => Role, () => UserRoles)
    roles: Role[]
    
    @HasMany(() => Post)
    posts: Post[]
    
    @HasMany(() => Like)
    likes: Like[]
```

Posts ->

```
@Table({ tableName: 'posts' })
export class Post extends Model<Post> {
    @Column({ type: DataType.INTEGER, unique: true, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true })
    id: number;

    @Column({ type: DataType.STRING, allowNull: false })
    title: string;

    @Column({ type: DataType.STRING, allowNull: false })
    content: string;

    @ForeignKey(() => User)
    @Column({ type: DataType.INTEGER })
    userId: number;

    @BelongsTo(() => User)
    author: User;

    @HasMany(() => Like)
    likes: Like[]
```

Likes ->

```
@Table({ tableName: 'likes' })
export class Like extends Model<Like> {
    @Column({ type: DataType.INTEGER, unique: true, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true })
    id: number;

    @ForeignKey(() => Post)
    @Column({ type: DataType.INTEGER })
    postId: number;

    @BelongsTo(() => Post)
    post: Post

    @ForeignKey(() => User)
    @Column({ type: DataType.INTEGER })
    userId: number;

    @BelongsTo(() => User)
    author: User    
}
```

**Repo**: https://github.com/keeeparis/Todo-Nest-React-Postgre

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was my mistake. When you editing columns, you manually need to delete some related tables in order to see the changes. Yes, simple as that.